# Вывод текста в браузер во время выполнения скрипта, а не после завершения

Tags: php

При работе длинных скриптов, бывает необходимость посмотреть за ходом выполнения, т.е. хочется выводить какие-либо данные на экран в браузер, прямо по ходу выполнения скрипта. Нашел данный пример в интернете:

```
ob_implicit_flush(1);
for($s='',$x=0;$x<10;$x++) { 
  ob_start(); 
  echo 'data';
  $s = ob_get_contents();
  ob_flush();
  flush();
  ob_end_clean();
  ob_end_flush(); 
  sleep(1);
}
```

По-идее данный пример должен каждую секунду 10 раз выводить слово `'data'`.
Ни на Денвере, ни на хостинге `NIC/RU-CENTER` данный пример не работает - сначала проходит 10 секунд, потом полностью выводится весь текст.
Несколько дней читаю интернет, у половины людей похожие конструкции с     `flush()/ob_flush()` работают, у половины нет. В целом, какой-либо ясности по вопросу нет. Как осуществить постоянный вывод в браузер?
Про `header('Content-Type: text/event-stream')` знаю, это не совсем то, что нужно, хочется чтобы в браузер выводился именно код с форматированием.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос довольно обширный, но я постараюсь вам ответить.

В чём тут может быть подвох.
Сервер: Apache который использует gzip и не отправляет страницу до завершения скрипта или подобные решения на nginx

Клиент:
Некоторые браузеры не начнут отрисовку из-за настроек "Перерисовывать всю страницу после полной загрузки". Некоторым браузерам необходимо получить хотя бы 500-100500 символов что бы взяться за работу при не полностью загруженной странице. Некоторые браузеры, если вы не выкидываете структуру документа , не начинают вывод пока не разберутся что с ним не так.

Самым простым решением если нужно просто проконтролировать долгий скрипт, запуск его через консоль. Если же нужен вывод в браузер то стоит попробовать Opera 12 с настройками перерисовывать страницу через 1 секунду

Внимание, велосипед.
В процессе выполнения записываем результат в текстовый файл и обновляем его [F5] или скриптом.

Answer (score 1):

@copenhagen вопрос не обширный, а очень простой, и современные технологии позволяют это решать. возьми websocket и можешь выводить информацию о работе своего скрипта хоть после каждое его строки. твой вопрос сводится к простому - как заставить сервер быть инициатором сообщений клиенту. ответ - websocket.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать конструкцию:

```
    while (ob_get_level())
      ob_end_flush();
```

Далее используйте необходимый вывод.

Answer (score 0):

Как сказал @Вадим, правильным ответом будет использование websocket. Сам по себе протокол HTTP не предусматривает такого понятия, как частичный ответ, и то, что временами такой функционал получается реализовать не означает, что первая попавшаяся на пути прокси не зарубит вам весь функционал. Прокотоло websocket-ов же был придуман специально для того, чтобы решить некоторые наболевшие в HTTP проблемы, в том числе, инициацию передачи на стороне сервера и постоянное подключение с не менее постоянным объемом данных. Да, чтобы реализовать желаемое с поддержкой вебсокетов, придется попотеть, но все остальные решения (кроме периодического опроса сервера) довольно печальны и, опять же, могут быть зарублены певой же проксей.

Однако, на мой взгляд туту вообще иная проблема: выполнение тяжелых вычислений внутри одного веб-запроса. Это абсолютно неконтролируемое поведение, которое легко как кладет сервер (если пришло n-цать человек и все ломанулись выполнять тяжелые вычисления), так и сам PHP по таймауту, в результате чего вообще непонятно, зачем он выполнялся. Ответы на HTTP-запросы должны выковываться, как свежие пирожки, с гигантской скоростью и в большом количестве, а сторонние задачи должны оставаться сторонними задачами. Специально для таких вещей придумали различные сервисы сообщения и очередей: от простого gearman, который вкручивается в проект за пятнадцать минут, до реализации AMQP, которая позволит настроить очень гибкий роутинг. Схема с использованием сервиса очередей предполагает, что в момент поступления запроса на тяжелое вычисление сервер скидывает задание в очередь и быстро дает ответ, а где-то в фоновом режиме трудится фиксированное количество рабочих процессов, постепенно разбирающих эту очередь. Такой подход не дает повалить сервис, не дает умереть PHP по таймауту, знатно помогает при масштабировании (рабочие процессы могут быть и на любом другом сервере), и вообще, единственное, что может с ним случиться - это переполнение очереди, которое обычно решается выделением большего количества ресурсов рабочим процессам. В этом случае можно просто сделать отдельный метод, который по айдишнику задачи будет возвращать статус ее выполнения, писать это дело в базу и доставать одним минимальным запросом. Если сделать это правильно, то метод получения данных о ходе выполнения можно будет оббивать аяксом хоть каждые сто миллисекунд, пока он легковесный, с сервисом ничего не случится.